# Will we be able to migrate TypeScript to Google AtScript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, atscript

Google is developing AtScript and - if I'm right - it will be introduced with Angular 2.0. Now, I am wondering if we will be able to migrate our TypeScript files to AtScript and continue with that new syntax.

O, can someone, with enough reputation, create the tag AtScript?
Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't really have to do with Dart? Is the question about Angular.js 1.x code written in TypeScript? What do you mean with "migrate"? Automatic code conversion?

Comment: AtScript won't be just for Dart. It will be Google's solution to ease JS development with the same purpose as TypeScript. I am wondering if we will be able to take our .ts files and open them as AtScript, just like you can open a javascript file in a TypeScript editor and start adding/changing TypeScript

Comment: "it will be introduced with Angular 2.0" - and abandoned by Angular 3.0 :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**: Yesterday (March 5th), the Google team announced that ATScript is [abandoned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHulaj5ZxbI&list=PLOETEcp3DkCoNnlhE-7fovYvqwVPrRiY7&t=1455). Angular 2.0 will be [built on Typescript 1.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/03/05/angular-2-0-built-on-typescript.aspx)

**original answer**

The AtScript team [has confirmed](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11YUzC-1d0V1-Q3V0fQ7KSit97HnZoKVygDxpWzEYW0U/mobilebasic?pli=1&viewopt=127) that they are collaborating with the TypeScript team (paragraph: Future of AtScript and TypeScript)

[Confirmation from the TypeScript team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/10/22/typescript-and-the-road-to-2-0.aspx) which specifically mentions Angular 2.0 (paragraph: From TypeScript 1.5 to TypeScript 2.0)

The latest indications are that At Script will be TypeScript + Annotations.

Short answer: **yes**.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is not actually being merged into AtScript, it is the other way around.

> We’re excited to announce that we have converged the TypeScript and
>   AtScript languages, and that Angular 2, the next version of the
>   popular JavaScript library for building web sites and web apps, will
>   be developed with TypeScript.

Source: [S. Somasegar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2015/03/05/typescript-lt-3-angular.aspx)

So you will be able to take the new version of TypeScript (1.5) when it lands - and you'll find everything in there.